# How to maintain multiple HTTP sessions with calls from a Servlet?

Tags: java, http, session, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am writing a Java servlet that needs to login to multiple websites, submit information on several pages, scrape the results, and then return consolidated results to the user on my own website. Presumably it would need to make these requests asynchronously to aggregate in parallel.

I'm not clear how to maintain a session across successive POST calls to the websites, and also if they would conflict with sessions that I have for each of *my* concurrent users.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sessions are servlet stuff. Write a session wrapper and create a session map so the session is associated to a key.

Comment: you need to use something like http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/. Each request to a foreign website should maintain its session by managing cookies sent from these foreign sites - this has nothing to do with the cookies a user of your site gets from your server to maintain his session.

Comment: "*Only one Servlet to login to multiple websites*"? Why?